# Batch file. How do you target a few files by the first few characters of their filename

Tags: batch-file

I want to move a few files from a folder to another folder, these few files have the same prefix in their filename, for example, myFile789789, myFile789798, myFile6787678, etc.

How do I target these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just all files starting with that name?

```
MOVE myFile* "c:\somewhere"
```

Comment: Glad to help.  DOS still comes in handy from time to time.  (You should tick correct answers.)

Answer (score 0):

```
move path1\myFile789789*.* path2
```

should do the trick.

Comment: .* returns all files with/without extensions.

Comment: So why use it?  If `*.* == *` then it is redundant to put the `.*`

Comment: actually i used it for a reason. i don't know what wei is trying to copy. maybe the file has an extension like `.dat` or `.bin`. if so, adding the extension by replacing the `.*` is the correct solution since `*` or `*.*` also returns other type of files and also folders (!). safe way is to use extensions and if i don't include `.*`, maybe wei couldn't find the way to put extension. i don't know his knowledge level. our examples here supposed to be patterns not the actual codes.

Comment: I agree, but the patterns should not be to be more restrictive or imply things that aren't sure.  For example there could also be directories with periods in them, so `*.*` would include those too(!).  It just doesn't seem relevant. The point is, and to quote "I don't know"...

Comment: `*` is exactly the equivalent to `*.*`. so, even paths which don't include `.` is selected by `*.*` just like `*`. i left `.*` part for replacement. that's my point.